# Stream Scheduling, reload application, published stream break

Tags: video-streaming, wowza

I am trying to build a video scheduling app using wowza 4.1.
I follow the tutorial [given here](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?145-How-to-schedule-streaming-with-Wowza-Streaming-Engine-(ServerListenerStreamPublisher)) , build an application and an smil file ,
as given . 
i am able to play schedule video. but when i make some changes in my smil file , 
i need to restart my app. which make my streaming break.

so i need an mechanism so that if i change my smil file , changes should reflect on published stream without stream breaking .